# Import csv file into SQL Server temptable, without specifying columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am currently trying to manipulate a fairly poor csv file into an SQL database. I would prefer to not use another program to amend the csv file. it's an output from a locked program, and the business have a general understanding of SQL, which is why I prefer an SQL solution.

What I want to do is take the 60 columns from this csv and import them all into a table, without specifying the column names. I have seen this BULK INSERT which allows me to put them into a table, but only one that's already created.

My actual end goal is to transform the data in the CSV so I have a table with just five columns, but step one is to get all of the data in, so that I can then grab the information that's relevant.

MY CSV file has a header row, but 59 of the 60 headers are blank, so there are no actual column headers in the sheet.

Example
SHEET,,,,
Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5,

Even better, if i could grab the columns I need (which in my case are columns 7, 31, 55 and 59) that would be even better.

I've scoured the internet and can't find the exact solution i'm looking for.

I've also tried to use SSIS for this, but honestly I find it unreliable sometimes and slight changes seem to break everything, so I gave up!! (My idea was flat file import > Derived Column > data conversion > OLE DB destination, but I got errors with the flat file import, which I can't seem to solve.

I would prefer to do it all through one SQL script if I can anyway, but any suggestions of the best way to achieve this are welcome.

Thank you,
Craig

Comment: _The csv file cannot be changed_ why yes, yes it can. Transform it with an external tool, such as a PowerShell script, before importing it into SQL Server. You could even insert it into SQL Server directly from PowerShell using the [System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) class.

Comment: You're looking for "easy" but tsql is not designed to interact with the file system. SSIS **is** designed as an extremely flexible ETL tool but it does have a rather high knowledge barrier. Perhaps an easier approach is to write a simple app that does the required "fixing" of your csv file. Could probably do that in Excel with some vba automation if needed. Once you have a well-structured CSV file, importing should be trivial.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yeah, I guess can't was the wrong word. I know I can manipulate it, and I would have no problem doing this with node.js or something similar. I was looking for an SQL only approach because i's something the wider team are comfortable with, while there is only a small development team who understand any code beyond SQL.

Comment: @SMor thanks - I think I am going to give SSIS another go, my main issue is trying to create a derived column/cast to boolean when a specific column  is "D" in the csv file. I want this to convert to a bit value of 1 in the SQL DB, or show as a bit value of 0 if the column value is blank or null.

Comment: I hear your pain around SSIS. I've had so much trouble over the years installing the designer tool and managing verson upgrades over the years, I'm glad it's on the way out.  _I have seen this BULK INSERT which allows me to put them into a table, but only one that's already created_ What's the actual reason that you don't want to use `BULK INSERT`? Just create a 60 column table and insert the data into it. Is there actually any issue with the file, like delimiters within data etc? Or is it just a giant file?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I could actually just create the table, honestly I don't know what my reluctance to do that was, other than having a messy table in the SQL DB that didn't look as pretty as I wanted it... I'll do that :D